# Wordpress theme OnePress missing section when change language

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a website made by Wordpress that is using the theme OnePress and i just realized that when i am changing the language from english to Japanese one section is missing i tried to check some other resources they requested me to download a plugin called PolyLang to customize each section regarding their language however the PolyLang seems not compatible with the theme because it giving me an error.
I am trying to play around but i could not find it yet so if anyone came across something like this please could you share how you solved it with everyone here.
Thank you